# UnauthorizedAccessException - Access to the path <>is denied. AWS hosted .NET MVC App

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a .NET Core 3.1 application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Windows Server Running on IIS). I have set up everything I need to pick a file and it was working in local successfully.

Below is the code written to access it.

In startup.cs (To get the host environment root location)

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
       Configuration = configuration;
       SetStaticAttributes(configuration, hostEnvironment);
}


private void SetStaticAttributes(IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
       StaticAttributes.RootDirectory = hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

In program.cs (Trying to write to a file)

```
pdfFilePath = Path.Combine(StaticAttributes.RootDirectory, CommonConstants.PDFFilePath, pdfFimeName);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilePath, Convert.FromBase64String(pdf));
```

When I deployed to AWS and tried to test it (using `Path.Combine`), I got below error in the logs.

```
{
"StatusCode": null,
"SubStatusCode": 0,
"StatusType": null,
"CustomMessage": null,
"InnerException": "null",
"ExceptionType": "DirectoryNotFoundException",
"Message": "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\wwwroot\\files\\filerepo\\jump.pdf'.",
"BaseException": "null",
"Source": "",
"Request": null
```

}

When I concatanate string with + i.e.

In Program.cs

```
pdfFilePath = StaticAttributes.RootDirectory + CommonConstants.PDFFilePath + pdfFimeName;
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilePath, Convert.FromBase64String(pdf));
```

I got below error in the logs.

```
{
"StatusCode": null,
"SubStatusCode": 0,
"StatusType": null,
"CustomMessage": null,
"InnerException": "null",
"ExceptionType": "UnauthorizedAccessException",
"Message": "Access to the path 'C:\\inetpub\\AspNetCoreWebApps\\app\\wwwroot\\files\\filerepo\\jump.pdf' is denied.",
"BaseException": "null",
"Source": "",
"Request": null}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put your deployment files on other hard drive, not `C:/` drive. Like `D:/` or `E:/` drive.

**Reason:**

Because some folders on the C: drive need more permissions.

You can add Physical Path Credentials for your IIS site.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am deploying it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk :/